# Messy [dllimport] and [dllexport] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

`__declspec( dllimport )` and `__declspec( dllexport )` are [C and C++ compiler directives to deal with DLL files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx). They are complementary to each other.

Currently, question about `__declspec( dllexport )` are tagged with [dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllexport) tag. Its excerpt states.

> [__declspec(dllexport) is a C and C++ compiler directive, which
>   automates exporting of functions or variables when creating a DLL
>   (Dynamic-link library).](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dllexport/info)

But then we have [dllimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport) tag. Unfortunately it is about completely different thing. Here's an excerpt.

> [The System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute class allows
>   managed .NET code to reference a Windows DLL through the magic of
>   Platform Invocation (P/Invoke for short). The
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace contains a wealth of tools to
>   allow .NET to efficiently and effectively use legacy DLLs.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dllimport/info)

It is about some .NET class and it does not mention `__declspec(dllimport)`. Because both `declspec` directives are closely related, the result is that many questions on `__declspec(dllimport)` are tagged with ".NET version" of [dllimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport) tag ([here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267811/declspecdllimport-dllexport-and-inheritance)).

I think it would be nice to make things clean and consistent. Options that come to my mind.

1. Add second meaning (that of `declspec(dllimport)`) to [dllimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dllimport) tag excerpt, like it is in case of [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functor) tag and C++ function-objects.
2. Use [declspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declspec) tag for questions about `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)`. But will people follow such guidance?
3. Create [declspec-dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declspec-dllexport) and [declspec-dllimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declspec-dllimport) tags.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Don't use [tag:functor] as an example. All those meaning [tag:function-object] should be re-tagged properly, as a functor can easily be expressed in C++ as well. I concede someone should remove the confusion from tag-wiki and excerp though. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285069/split-functor-tag-and-merge-c-functor-with-function-object

Comment: @Deduplicator In case of functors I agree with you, but what can be done if community does not care...

Comment: IMO the .NET questions should be tagged [pinvoke] instead (the proper name of the .NET mechanism). I'm primarily a C# developer but if you tell me *"dllimport"* I'll immediately think about `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not two meanings here, only one.

The problem is that DLL importing is rather broader in scope than the tag wiki suggests.  DLL is already a Windows-centric term, what's most important is that the DLL export table does not contain type information, so the DLL functions cannot be called until the consuming application provides the function signature.

Both `__declspec(dllimport)` and `DllImportAttribute` (as well as DLL importing syntax in every other Windows language, eg [VB6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716201%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and [Java](https://jna.java.net/)) are concerned with specifying the signature of a function found in a DLL, to allow calling it correctly.

Feel free to update the tag wiki to be less .NET-centric.

I wouldn't recommend trying to create an exhaustive list of DLL importing syntax in every language under the sun.

Comment: As you have opened my eyes, I see that there is also third way - through LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress combo. Do you think this should be mentioned also? You don't recommend, but in the tag wiki this could work.

Comment: @doc that's a way of using DLLs without first importing them. Well actually .NET pinvoke uses dynamic loading and not an import table, but from the language perspective it is still a static import.

Answer (score 1):

As the top answerer for both these tags, I can confidently state that there is *never* an issue determining which of the tags apply.  Questioners are never at a loss either.  The language tag disambiguates.

This doesn't need fixed.

Comment: If that's your point then [dllimport] tag guideline should mention `__declspec(dllimport)`. Of course in such case there's no issue when [dllimport] tag should apply, because it can mean either `declspec(dllimport)` or .NET [DllImport]. But it should be mentioned when to use each tag in guideline to bring order, hence my "question".

Comment: Can't you just edit the tag wiki?

Comment: Of course I can. The point is, that I am not sure if it is appropriate to add another meaning to [dllimport] tag or to use different solution. So I am asking for opinions. If that's your opinion to add another meaning to [dllimport] tag, then thank you.

Comment: @doc: But it is not another meaning.  It is the same meaning, expressed in a different programming language.